# Why my bounty question doesn't show up on feature tab at SO

Tags: support, bounty

I have started bounty of 50 reputation at Stackoverflow for one of my questions.Why it doesn't show up on feature tab?

My question got that special bounty symbol though.

Comment: How long has it been? Did you clear your cache?

Comment: It has been about 2 hours.I don't know,how to clear cache.

Comment: I just googled and found out abt cache.My cache setting is good.Nothing is selected,so all browsing data,and cookies are already there

Comment: Can you please link your question where you put the bounty on

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776784/output-data-from-database-using-htmlspecialchars-that-has-been-filtered-using>

Comment: ^ So you set your bounty from this acc? And if yes here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=featured&pageSize=50 at the end (BTW: If you have multiple accounts, they will be eventually merged)

Comment: why don't I see that on SO home page feature tab?It is in php's feature tab,if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @user3255788 It's there. The featured tab is ordered by how much time is remaining in the bounty, from least time to most, so yours is currently on the very last page of the featured tab, a little over halfway down the page. As the time remaining in the bounty decreases, it will move closer to the first page of that tab.

Comment: Now make sense.Thanks for clearing the point.  +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From Kendra's comment)

It is there. The featured tab is ordered by how much time is remaining in the bounty, from least time to most.  Yours is currently on the very last page of the featured tab, a little over halfway down the page. As the time remaining in the bounty decreases, it will move closer to the first page of that tab.